# React.js Hooks Set State Function From Event Listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you please explain why the following results in an infinite loop with the following error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from 'react';

function MyImageComponent(props) {
  const {
    images
  } = props;

  const [windowWidth, updateWindowDimensions] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  window.addEventListener('resize', updateWindowDimensions(window.innerWidth)); //error here


  return (
    <div>
    {windowWidth}
    </div>
  );

}

export default MyImageComponent;
```

I believe I can solve using the `useEffect` API but I don't understand conceptually what the problem is...  it appears the render is being called multiple times because state is being set in a loop... but given the update function `updateWindowDimensions` is binded to an event listener which is not running infinitely I don't understand it.

To note: the error appears with or without a window resize.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('resize', () => updateWindowDimensions(window.innerWidth))`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky omg  I see, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are not handling the resize event handler correctly. The first argument of the resize event handler would be a [resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event). Also you would pass a function to a handler rather than executing a function as a handler. Try the following instead:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => updateWindowDimensions(window.innerWidth))
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 2):

@Alexander Staroselsky answer will solve your exact issue, but on each render `window.addEventListener` will be called and new event handler will be assigned to 'resize' event. So you'll quickly end up with hundreds of the same event listeners calling `updateWindowDimensions(window.innerWidth)` (You may see it by adding `console.log(window.innerWidth)` to callback).

I suggest to use `useEffect` with empty dependency list. So it will be called exactly once and bind one event listener to `resize` event.

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        updateWindowDimensions(window.innerWidth)
  })}, []);
```

Comment: This is a great answer and important point. I’d take it one step further and add example of clean up (removing event listener) from the hook.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification on the need for lifecycle methods.